Python PIL makes CMYK image significantly lighter when converting to RGB
I am processing images with PIL. When I open and convert some images to RGB they get completely deteriorated.
One example of such an image is the following one:
(Image too heavy to upload)
https://i.ibb.co/0JGzsC8/input-image1.jpg
After the conversion I get the following:

I run the following code:
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("input_image1.jpg")
img.convert("RGB").save("output_image1.jpg", format="jpeg")

I would expect that the output image looks like the input image.
This is what I get when I print img.mode:

'CMYK'

This is what I get when I print img.info:
'jfif': 257,
'jfif_version': (1, 1),
'dpi': (300, 300),
'jfif_unit': 1,
'jfif_density': (300, 300),
'adobe': 100,
'adobe_transform': 2

The pillow version is:
pillow==10.2.0
These other posts didn't help:
How to keep same colors when converting CMYK image to RGB using PIL?
Preserving colors during CMYK to RGB transformation in PIL
Convert from CMYK to RGB

Do not use CMYK. You lose information by many conversions (tips: printers will convert back to RGB (or linear combination of it, like XYZ), and then with the ink specific densities. (and jpeg uses normally YCC [often seen wrongly written as YUV]) -- In any case CMYK usually it is used for subtractive colours, so by mixing you lose saturation), but it is a good test for "soft printing": when you print you get soft colours.
